# How lock a file during write so that it cannot be read while open?

Tags: uwp

In the old days I would set the shared mode for a file when opening.  Does UWP have any similar concept?  Nothing seems obvious.

Comment: You can always open a file using [CreateFile2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422.aspx), requesting a *dwShareMode* of `0` (i.e. no sharing).

Answer (score 0):

[`FileShare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) class is belong to .net APIs but it is also supported in uwp app. `System.IO` namespace has many APIs support uwp apps, details you can reference [System.IO namespaces for UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185496.aspx). So you can use [`FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) for reading and writing file and set the `FileShare` to `none` will make the file cannot be read. For example:

```
StorageFolder localfolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile samplefile = await localfolder.GetFileAsync("sample.txt");
FileStream stream = new FileStream(samplefile.Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
```